# R cannot be resolved in eclipse android project

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, r.java-file

This is my third time setting up my android env in eclipse (for different computers).
This time I cannot get it to work, something didnt get set up correctly or I'm forgetting something.

gen folder is not getting generated and of course no R.java file. I have searched online everywhere and cannot find a solution to this problem. That applies to creating a new project and using android sample projects.

No I do not have import android.R, restarted eclipse mult times, did clean project, build project, no new updates to be installed.. 
Thanks in advance, any help would be great!

Comment: possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Comment: I have read that one. And seemed like the guy had import android.R that eclipse adds, that is not the case for me.

Comment: Do you ADK 14? http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields    though the link says only switch cases, its affecting the generation of R.java for me in this system with latest ADK.

Comment: It wasn't version dependent. It resolved itself now..

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to a quirk in Eclipse. Often, but not always, it is solved by this magic invocation: Pressing ctrl+shift+O, then "Project Clean" (uncheck "Build automatically" first), then "Build All" and see if it works.

Comment: I didn't get to try your magic trick :) It started to work for some reason. I messed with adk manager, installed some extra stuff, restarted again and it resolved.. The saddest part I dont even know what really fixed it. Eclipse drives me insane sometimes :D

Answer (score 0):

TRy closing and starting eclipse again.